# Cannot install Google OR-Tools due to missing dotnet-test_dotnet

Tags: c#, .net-core, or-tools, dotnet-cli

I want to use the library [OR-Tools of Google](https://developers.google.com/optimization) for mathematical optimization.

For this I followed the installation instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/optimization/install/dotnet/windows). In the end, it says to run `tools\make test_dotnet` on a x64 Native Tools Command Prompt which I did.
The result was error 1 in the image below
[image]
However, simply running `dotnet` worked (2) and I also checked that `C:\Program Files\dotnet` (where dotnet.exe is located) is added to my PATH variable.

So I checked the makefile of OR-Tools in line 486 as mentioned in the error message. There it says:

```
##############
##  DOTNET  ##
##############
.PHONY: dotnet test_dotnet
ifndef DOTNET_BIN
dotnet test_dotnet:
    @echo the command 'dotnet' was not found in your PATH
    exit 127
```

So the problem seems to be `dotnet test_dotnet`. Running this command shows the error that there is no executable file with the name `dotnet-test_dotnet` found. [This site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/troubleshoot-usage-issues) tells me to look in my user folder/.dotnet/tools. However, I only have .dotnet, but not .dotnet/tools, although I installed .NetCore SDK 2.1.

I am not sure if it is mainly a .NET problem or rather a Google OR-Tools problem. Can you help me?

Edit: As @LaurentPerron said, `make test_dotnet` is not necessary, but only an additional check. However, OR-Tools actually do not seem to work. When I call `LinearSolver.Solver.CreateSolver("SCIP")`, it gives me an TypeInitializerException for the class SWIGExceptionHelper, and a DllNotFoundException for the DLL google-ortools-native.

Remark: I know that Google recommends using Visual Studio 2019. However, I used OR-Tools with Visual Studio 2017 on my previous computer and it worked. For VS2019, my company would have to buy a new license. And as it worked with VS2017 before, I first want to make sure what the problem is, before I ask my boss for a new license.

Comment: You will need dotnet 3.1 or 6.0.
You need to install visual studio 2019 redistributable libraries. VS2017 is not supported as the C++ requires extensive support for C++17 features.

Comment: *I currently cannot use VS2019* - soo.. How about 2022?

Comment: we have not tested if it works.

Comment: And you do not need to run 'make test_dotnet'. This is just an additional check.

Comment: Thank you! I edited the question to make clear why I want to use VS2017 and that not only the test fails. I installed Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2022 Redistributable - that should correct, right?

Answer (score 0):

The issue here, is our Makefile didn't detect your dotnet installation.
so `DOTNET_BIN` is undefined and thus you pass in the code path having the error message...

ref:

```
# Check for required build tools
DOTNET = dotnet
ifeq ($(SYSTEM),win)
DOTNET_BIN := $(shell $(WHICH) $(DOTNET) 2> NUL)
```

src: https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/2cb85b4eead4c38e1c54b48044f92087cf165bce/makefiles/Makefile.dotnet.mk#L13-L16

note: on Windows this should use `tools/which.exe`.

Could you run and show us the return of the command:
`make detect_dotnet` ?

src: https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/2cb85b4eead4c38e1c54b48044f92087cf165bce/makefiles/Makefile.dotnet.mk#L1154-L1157

Comment: Thank you for your answer. `tools\win\which.exe dotnet` returns `C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.EXE`, so it seems that dotnet is found, right? The result of `tools\make.exe detect_dotnet` is `DOTNET_BIN =
/usr/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token \`newline'
/usr/bin/sh: -c: line 0: \`echo off & echo('
make: *** [Makefile:677: detect_dotnet] Error 258`

Comment: Makefile doesn't play well with space in path, try to use short name like `C:\PROGRA~1`...

Comment: Ok, I installed .NET SDK 3.1 to `C:\Progra~1\dotnet'. The path exists in PATH environment variable and `which dotnet` returns `C:\Progra~1\dotnet\dotnet.EXE`. However, `make detect_dotnet` still fails with the same error as in my previous comment. Also the makefile in my unpacked or-tools_VisualStudio2019-64bit_v9.2.9972 looks different than the one, you linked in your answer. Is that normal?